# How to animate text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement animated text i.e. moving the text from bottom (half of the page) to the top like marquee. I don't get any good code. Does any one know how this is implemented in JavaScript or jQuery or DHTML?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @alex: +1 for that. It's even worse than "Ajax"... @Hema: If you don't "get any good code", how about writing some? If you can't figure it out, post your attempt here and people can improve on it.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: +1 for "do some writing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code as the answer below but, it sets the TEXT location to be at half the page's height, and then animates it to top:

```
//Calculate where is HALF of the page (half the window height)
var start_pos = screen.height/2;

//Set starting TOP location
$(".text").css("top", start_pos+"px");    

//Animate to the END location, which is 0px
$(".text").animate({ top:0+"px" }, 5000, function() { alert("Animation Complete"); });

​
```

Answer (score 5):

use jquery

```
  $('#mydiv').animate({
    top: 0
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skmCn/) here

Comment: thanks.  i need the text must be move from bottom to top and again( continuously like marquee up direction). Could you please give me an complete answer

Comment: Tell me Why dont you use the marquee it self, it is much better than writing these scripts.